# Brute Force Solution to Shortest Path in a directed weighted graph with negative cycle

Tags: java, shortest-path, breadth-first-search, brute-force, weighted-graph

I'm trying to write brute-force algorithm to find the shortest path from s to t. The graph is weighted and also has negative weighted edges. No need to think about negative cycles. Basically exit, if there is so.

I've written Bellman-Ford Algorithm to solve this problem. It works very well. (Incase of "use better algorithms" comments) However, as a second step, I need to implement Brute Force Algorithm. I tried to write it over Breadth First Search Alg.,however as i mentioned, there are negative edges. therefore, in some of the cases, i need to revisit some nodes. 
Brute Force Alg. for graphs which have nonnegative edges:

```
Distance(s, t):
  for each path p from s to t: 
    compute w(p)
  return p encountered with smallest w(p)
```

Comment: If the presence of negative edges in a particular graph means that you can reduce the cost of a path between your two nodes by adding a loop, then you can find paths between those nodes with arbitrarily low cost.  In that case, what exactly does "shortest path" mean to you?

Comment: In that case, negative cycle exists. So, I can exit  if that occurs. I don't need to find any path.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand what you're asking.  Maybe the question I should have posed was "what does 'brute force' mean to you?"  Typically, that means exhaustively testing all the possibilities, and if you're prepared to detect loops and reject cases where there are paths with negative loops then I don't see what prevents you from (otherwise) using brute force.